# VSCode Pull Requests - Organization

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have my personal GitHub account which has been given access to Repos that exist as part of an organization. I'm trying to create a pull-request from within VSCode for these Repos, but I get the below error.

Is there a setting I'm just missing?

```
[Info] GitHubRepository> Creating pull requests failed: HttpError: Validation Failed: {"resource":"PullRequest","field":"head","code":"invalid"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> HttpError
> ```

Check first if you have a `git config credential.helper` set (to, for instance on windows, `manager-core`)

If you have, that means the wrong credentials (username/password) are cached in said credential helper. They are not the ones for your organization GitHub account.

See GitHub "[Caching your GitHub credentials in Git](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git)" and update them.

Comment: The problem though is that my credentials are for my personal GitHub account which is allocated access to repos within an organization. I don’t have separate creds for  repos within my org

Comment: @Nolan Then try and use as a password a PAT with org scope. (https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: I take it back. Wound up removing all GitHub related creds from my credential manager, signed back in, boom!  Worked perfectly. Thanks!